# git log -L for C# files (*.cs files)

Tags: c#, git

I know git log -L is mostly meant to be used for *.c files, but is there a way to use git log -L for C# files as well?

I tried to trace my Application_Start history:

```
git log -p -L :Application_Start:Global.asax.cs
```

but getting an error:

> fatal: -L parameter 'Application_Start' starting at line 1: no match

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was a silly mistake but posting it here anyway in case it helps anyone - add `*.cs diff=csharp` to your .gitattributes file. You can do it by running this in Git Bash (at repo root dir):

```
echo "*.cs diff=csharp">>.gitattributes
```

After that it should work.

NOTE: Also if you have comments at the end of the function they break that too:

```
protected void Application_Start() // this comment breaks git log -L
```

so you'll need to remove them and commit the change.

Comment: the fact that the presence of a comment breaks the regex is a Git bug, in my opinion. You should report it to the Git mailing list: https://git-scm.com/community